# iPad Orientation in Portrait for Unknown Reason

Tags: swift, ipad, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I have a game in SpriteKit in landscape. It runs fine on any iPhone, but when I run the app on an iPad, it is always in portrait. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** First of all select the orientation in the general part of your App:

[image: Orientation]

**2.** A very common error is to not check the `info.plist`. There you can set the supported orientations for each iPhone and iPad. (Make sure to delete both iPad Portrait options)

---

[image: Orientation]